# why The Pointer "téte" has The Value Nil?

Tags: c

> **here i created a chained chain (dynamic memorie) so after this this
> the pointer tete should point in the first element of the list so that
> it contains his adresse. but it look it dosen't**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>>
int main (){
    struct element{
    int val;
    struct element *suiv;
    };
    typedef struct element element;
    element *tete,*p,*q;
    int i,X;
    tete = NULL;
    for (i=0;i<4;i++){
        p = malloc(sizeof(*p));
        printf("veillez saisir la valeur du element");
        scanf("%d",&X);
        p->val = X;
        if (tete = NULL){
            tete = p;
            q = p;
        }
        else{
            q->suiv = p;
            q = p;
        }
    }
    if (tete != NULL){
        p->suiv = NULL;
    }
    printf("%p",tete->val);
    return 0;
}
```

> it should look like this the diagram as "tete" contain the adress of
> first element.
>
> https://ibb.co/jDzRj2b

Comment: You should really enable compiler warnings: https://godbolt.org/z/G3n53hn48 (and if you don't understand a warning, these are usually quite easy to search for).

Comment: Also, please format your code properly. People don't want poorly formatted code.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (tete = NULL){
```

`NULL` is assigned to `tete` here. Then, the assignment expression is evaluated to `NULL` (the value assigned). `NULL` is treated as false when used as condition, so `tete = p;` after that is not executed. This is why `tete` remains `NULL`.

You should do comparision instead of assignment in the line:

```
if (tete == NULL){
```

(use two `=`s instead of one)